# Latex TIKZ spring and damper in a row (and a spring in parallel)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I dont get into the syntax of drawing a damper and a spring in row (without a mass or anything else between them): all i can do is draw them in parallel:
another thing: how do I control the length of the spring?

Thank you a lot for you help!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,outer sep=0pt,thick}]
\tikzstyle{spring}=[thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm,post length=0.3cm,segment length=6}]
\tikzstyle{damper}=[thick,decoration={markings,  
  mark connection node=dmp,
  mark=at position 0.5 with 
  {
    \node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum width=15pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {};
    \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(2pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(2pt,0)$);
    \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-5pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,5pt)$);
  }
}, decorate]
\tikzstyle{ground}=[fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=0.75cm,minimum height=0.3cm]


\begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]

\node (wall) [ground, rotate=-90, minimum width=3cm,yshift=-3cm] {};
\node (walle) [ground, rotate=-90, minimum width=3cm,yshift=3cm] {};


\draw (wall.north east) -- (wall.north west);
\draw (walle.south west) -- (walle.south east);


\draw [spring, width=15pt] (wall.170) -- ($(walle.south west)!(walle.170)!(walle.south east)$);
\draw [damper] (wall.10) -- ($(walle.south west)!(walle.10)!(walle.south east)$);

\node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum width=15pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {};



\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,outer sep=0pt,thick}]
\tikzstyle{spring}=[thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm,post length=0.3cm,segment length=6}]
\tikzstyle{damper}=[thick,decoration={markings,
  mark connection node=dmp,
  mark=at position 0.5 with
  {
    \node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum width=15pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {};
    \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(2pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(2pt,0)$);
    \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-5pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,5pt)$);
  }
}, decorate]
\tikzstyle{ground}=[fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=0.75cm,minimum height=0.3cm]


\begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]

\node (wall) [ground, rotate=-90, minimum width=3cm,yshift=-3cm] {};
\node (walle) [ground, rotate=-90, minimum width=3cm,yshift=3cm] {};


\draw (wall.north east) -- (wall.north west);
\draw (walle.south west) -- (walle.south east);


\draw [spring, line width=15pt] ($(wall.north west)!0.2!(wall.north east)$) -- ++(3.5cm,0)coordinate (m);
\draw [damper] (m) -- ($(walle.south west)!0.2!(walle.south east)$);

\node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum width=15pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {};

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**How to improve code?**

First don't use `\tikzstyle` but `tikzset`. Instead of rotating individual nodes, forst draw them and rotate the entire piece. This makes you to visualise directions and anchors (like `(wall.north east)` etc) easier.

Further, you can set the length of spring by using relative coordinates like:

```
 \draw [spring, line width=15pt] ($(wall.north west)!0.2!(wall.north east)$) -- ++(0,3.5cm);
```

This means - "from a point at a distance of 0.2 of the total length from north west and north east (measured from north west)". `-- ++(0,3.5cm)` means - to a distance 0cm in x-direction and 3.5cm in y-direction".

Once the spring is drawn, we put a coordinate at the end of the spring

```
............++(0,3.5cm)coordinate (m);
```

From `(m)` we draw the `damper` to `walle`:

```
\draw [damper] (m) -- ($(walle.south west)!0.2!(walle.south east)$);
```

where the second part is as explained before.

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,outer sep=0pt,thick}]
\tikzset{
    spring/.style = {thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm,post length=0.3cm,segment 
                        length=6}},
    damper/.style ={thick,decoration={markings,
                        mark connection node=dmp,
                        mark=at position 0.5 with
                            {
                            \node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum 
                                    width=15pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {};
                            \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(2pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south 
                                    west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(2pt,0)$);
                            \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-5pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,5pt)$);
                            }
                        }, decorate},
    ground/.style ={fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=0.75cm,minimum height=0.3cm}
}

\begin{scope}[rotate=-90,transform shape]       %%% rotate here, both options needed.

\node (wall) [ground, minimum width=3cm,anchor=center] at (0,0) {};
\node (walle) [ground, minimum width=3cm,anchor=center] at (0,6) {};


\draw (wall.north east) -- (wall.north west);
\draw (walle.south west) -- (walle.south east);


\draw [spring, line width=15pt] ($(wall.north west)!0.2!(wall.north east)$) -- ++(0,3.5cm)coordinate (m);
\draw [damper] (m) -- ($(walle.south west)!0.2!(walle.south east)$);
 %
%% now a parallel spring
\draw [spring, line width=15pt] ($(wall.north west)!0.8!(wall.north east)$) -- ($(walle.south west)!0.8!(walle.south east)$);

%\node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum width=15pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {};

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a very lot!!
[image]
Here's my final code for all beeing interested:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,outer sep=0pt,thick}]
\tikzset{
    spring/.style = {thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm,post length=0.3cm,segment 
                        length=6}},
    damper/.style ={thick,decoration={markings,
                        mark connection node=dmp,
                        mark=at position 0.5 with
                            {
                            \node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum 
                                    width=15pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {};
                            \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(1pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south 
                                    west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(1pt,0)$);
                            \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-5pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,5pt)$);
                            }
                        }, decorate},
    ground/.style ={fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=0.75cm,minimum height=0.3cm}
}

\begin{scope}[rotate=-90,transform shape]       %%% rotate here, both options needed.

\node (wall) [ground, minimum width=3cm,anchor=center] at (0,0) {};
\node (walle) [ground, minimum width=3cm,anchor=center] at (0,6) {};

\draw (wall.north east) -- (wall.north west);
\draw (walle.south west) -- (walle.south east);

%% now a parallel spring
\draw [line width=0.8pt] ($(wall.north west)!0.2!(wall.north east)$) -- ++(0,2cm)coordinate (z);
\draw [spring] (z) -- ++(0,2cm)coordinate (t); 
\draw [line width=0.8pt] (t) -- ($(walle.south west)!0.2!(walle.south east)$);

\end{scope}


\begin{scope}[rotate=-90,transform shape]       %%% rotate here, both options needed.

\draw [line width=0.8pt] ($(wall.north west)!0.8!(wall.north east)$) -- ++(0,1cm)coordinate (z);
\draw [spring] (z) -- ++(0,2cm)coordinate (t); 
\draw [damper] (t) -- ++(0,2cm)coordinate (u); 
\draw [line width=0.8pt] (u) -- ($(walle.south west)!0.8!(walle.south east)$);

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why you are using two `scope`s? Only one is enough. Comment lines 38 and 41.